# Reading an XLSX file using Java and Apache POI 3.8

Tags: java, apache, xlsx

I am trying to read in an XLSX file with Apache POI but I am not able to read the file. I got this error with the code shown below:

```
A sheet hyperlink must either have a location, or a relationship
```

Please help me pinpoint where I am going wrong:

```
public void readFile() throws Exception {       
    String filePath="/home/work1/DATA FEB/MANI-FINAL/ENGG-1.xlsx";
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(filePath));
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
}
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sheet hyperlink must either have a location, or a relationship. Found:
<xml-fragment ref="J502:J503" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"/>
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.<init>(XSSFHyperlink.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initHyperlinks(XSSFSheet.java:182)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:139)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:200)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:179)
```

Comment: . but i am not  being able to read the file .. please help where i am going wrong

Comment: got dis error  A sheet hyperlink must either have a location, or a relationship.

Comment: Please update your question with exceptions & other details rather than adding comments.

Comment: Try reading an empty non complicated xlsx file and see what happens. There could be some special junk in the file that poi doesnt support yet.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276738/exception-when-reading-xlsm-workbook-via-apache-poi

Comment: Related defect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276738/exception-when-reading-xlsm-workbook-via-apache-poi